# Select Count(*) on inner join

Tags: sql

Can someone correct this statement or make it more efficient.  Thank you:

```
SET @intAnswer =  (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM episode INNER JOIN
episodejoin ON episode.epi_id = episodejoin.epj_epi_id_dest INNER JOIN
episodetype ON episode.epi_ety_id = episodetype.ety_id
WHERE (episodejoin.epj_epi_id_src = @EpisodeID)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current statement? Do you have indexes on columns being used in join and where clause?

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for your quick response! It's examination question at uni, the question asked is what is wrong with this statement and how would you write the statement?  Or in your opinion does this statement look legal?

Comment: Well, you most likely do not need a join to `episodetype` considering that it's supposed to serve as dictionary table.

Comment: Thank you!  So, apart from the join episodetype, in your expert opinion the statement would return a count successfully?

Comment: So, apart from the join episodetype, in your expert opinion the statement would return a count successfully? Anything else you see wrong with the statement, please let me know. "I already changed SELECT @intAnswer = count(*) to SET "@intAnswer =  (SELECT COUNT(*)"

Comment: The `()` are unbalanced.

Comment: Thank you, ULick.  Can you change this query into a sub query, and give me the syntax? I think it would make the query run faster